# Converter porcentagem

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, group-by, where, count

Estou com dificuldade para converter %

meu codigo:

```
select 
 veiculos , qtd , trunc(qtd / sum(qtd) over()* 100, 4 ) PERC
from (
   select 
  ent_datahora_entrada , veiculos  , count(*) qtd
from (
      select          
        to_char(ent_datahora_entrada, 'mm/yyyy')  ent_datahora_entrada,          
        case when to_char(ent_datahora_entrada, 'hh24:mi')>='00:00'
              and to_char(ent_datahora_entrada, 'hh24:mi')<='07:59' then '0 as 8'
             when to_char(ent_datahora_entrada, 'hh24:mi')>='08:00'
              and to_char(ent_datahora_entrada, 'hh24:mi')<='15:59' then '8 as 16'
             when to_char(ent_datahora_entrada, 'hh24:mi')>='16:00'
              and to_char(ent_datahora_entrada, 'hh24:mi')<='23:59' then '16 as 0'                 
        end veiculos
      from entradas_saidas
      where to_char(ent_datahora_entrada, 'YYYY') = 2019
) 

group by ent_datahora_entrada, veiculos
);
```

Esta saindo assim:

```
VEICULOS    | QTD   |PERC
8 as 16     | 3     |1.3043
16 as 0     | 29    |12.6086
8 as 16     | 29    |12.6086
```

quero que saia assim:

```
MES     | VEICULOS  | QTD   |PERC
03/2019 |8 as 16    | 3     |1%
03/2019 |16 as 0    | 29    |12%
08/2019 |8 as 16    | 29    |12%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Débora, pelo que entendi está faltando apenas acrescentar a coluna *ent_datahora_entrada* no primeiro *Select* e alterar o segundo parâmetro da função *Trunc* para 0:

```
select
  ent_datahora_entrada,  
  veiculos, 
  qtd, 
  trunc(qtd / sum(qtd) over() * 100, 0) PERC 
from 
(
  select
    ent_datahora_entrada, 
    veiculos, 
    count(*) qtd 
  from
  (
    select
      to_char(ent_datahora_entrada, 'mm/yyyy') ent_datahora_entrada,
      case 
        when to_char(ent_datahora_entrada, 'hh24:mi') >= '00:00' and 
             to_char(ent_datahora_entrada, 'hh24:mi') <= '07:59' 
          then '0 as 8' 
        when to_char(ent_datahora_entrada, 'hh24:mi') >= '08:00' and 
             to_char(ent_datahora_entrada, 'hh24:mi') <= '15:59' 
          then '8 as 16' 
        when to_char(ent_datahora_entrada, 'hh24:mi') >= '16:00' and 
             to_char(ent_datahora_entrada, 'hh24:mi') <= '23:59' 
          then '16 as 0'
      end veiculos 
    from entradas_saidas 
    where to_char(ent_datahora_entrada, 'YYYY') = 2019 
  )
  group by ent_datahora_entrada, veiculos 
);
```

Espero que ajude

Comment: Muito Obrigada! Super ajudou.